# clang compiler being able to offload OpenMP region to GPU

Tags: c, clang, openmp, offloading

I read that clang compiler can offload OpenMP regions to GPUs. However, I am
confused on the way to compile the code with clang. The clang version that is 
installed in our cluster is 3.9.0 (tags/RELEASE_390/final 288133). The code I
want to offload is basically a matrix-matrix multiplication:

```
#pragma omp target parallel for  shared(C,P,T) private(i,j,k)
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
      for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
        C[i][j] += P[i][k]*T[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
```

I am compiling with

```
clang -O3 -fopenmp-targets=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu mm.c
clang-3.9: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp-targets=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
```

What I don't know is if my installed version of clang is being able to offload code to GPUs and if so, how could I do it. Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** According to the [Clang 3.9.0 Release Notes](http://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#openmp-support-in-clang) it is not:

> Currently Clang supports OpenMP 3.1 and all non-offloading features of OpenMP 4.0/4.5. Offloading features are under development.

---

I couldn't find anything in the newer release notes on whether or not it has been *officially* added in the meantime to a newer version. There seems to be some support though. The [libomptarget](https://github.com/clang-omp/libomptarget) doc states two plugins

- generic 64 bit for the following targets:

  - `powerpc64-ibm-linux-gnu`
  - `powerpc64le-ibm-linux-gnu`
  - `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`
- cuda, for the target (see [this](https://llvm.org/docs/NVPTXUsage.html)):

  - `nvptx-nvidia-cuda`
  - `nvptx64-nvidia-cuda`

Maybe this [document](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6510-jeff-larkin-targeting-gpus-openmp.pdf) helps you if you want to try building your own Clang.

A list of OpenMP implementations can be found [here](https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/). GCC 6.1 and newer fully supports OpenMP 4.5. Offloading seems to be support by GCC 5 and later, but for Nvidia GPUs only via OpenACC, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading).

In general, the support of the `target` construct, i.e. offloading, is not equal with GPU (or any specific device) support, as this requires device-specific implementations per device. The trivial support would be offloading to to the host device, e.g. x86-CPU, which wouldn't be beneficial for anything but testing or compatibility in the absence of accelerator devices.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 7, clang supports OpenMP offloading to Nvidia GPUs (http://releases.llvm.org/7.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#id12):

> Clang gained basic support for OpenMP 4.5 offloading for NVPTX target.
>
> To compile your program for NVPTX target use the following options: `-fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` for 64 bit platforms or `-fopenmp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx-nvidia-cuda` for 32 bit platform.